# How to add buttons to JPanel starting from the right?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, layout-manager

How to add buttons and other components to a `JPanel` starting from the right to the left? I have used `BorderLayout` manager to do that but it did not work, they are inserted in the middle of the screen!

How can I do that?

Comment: the right of the panel I meant!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Add additional `JPanel` and `FlowLayout` with right alignment.**

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT), 0, 5); // 0 for horizontal gap
```

Comment: it worked but now there is a space between buttons, I need them to be one besides the other with no space!

Comment: I did that with another constructor of FlowLayout as you have mentioned thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

It's import to clarify the question, as there is a difference between something been aligned to the right and things been added in right to left order...

## Aligned to the right...

There are a number ways you might align components to the right, you could use a `GridBagLayout`, but the simplest might be to use a `FlowLayout`

[image: Aligned to the right]

```
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
            add(new JLabel("Aligned"));
            add(new JLabel("to"));
            add(new JLabel("the"));
            add(new JLabel("right"));
        }

    }

}
```

## Added to the right to left...

This simply uses `Component#setComponentOrientation` and sets it to `ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT` to change the direction in which components are laid out

[image: Starting from the right]

```
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
            setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
            add(new JLabel("Starting"));
            add(new JLabel("from"));
            add(new JLabel("the"));
            add(new JLabel("right"));
        }

    }

}
```